# How to close window after iframe form submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a blank page with an iframe that displays a form from an **external domain outside my control**. I'm trying to write a bit of Javascript/jQuery that will close the window after the form is submitted.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <script>
        $('iframe input[type="submit"]').on('click', function () {
            window.close();
        });
    </script>

    <iframe src="SomeOtherDomain.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

Nothing happens when I click the button though. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I'm not sure if it makes a difference or not but it looks like the iframe calls a second iframe... I've got an iframe inside an iframe.

Comment: Is `form` in `window` opened using `window.open()`?

Comment: @guest271314 - No, I never called window.open().

Comment: If you do not have control over the domain which is set at `.src` of `<iframe>`, not sure if it is possible to attach event listeners to user action at `iframe`. `javascript` at Question is at `parent` `window` of `<iframe>` element, correct?

Comment: @guest271314 - correct.

Answer (score 0):

So long as your iframe src is from the same domain this will work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var f = $('#myframe')[0];
var win = f.contentWindow;

//Created test environment in IFrame with ID "myframe"
$(win.document.body).append('<form><input type="submit" value="click me"/></form>');
$(win.document).on('submit', function () {
    setTimeout(function () { $(f).remove();  }, 1000)
});

});
```

Simply remove the element but remember you can't get the contentDocument from an iframe that is not of the same domain.

Working solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/f3eayurw/

Comment: Unfortunately, the iframe source is another domain I have no control over.

Comment: I believe what you're asking for is not possible then. Cross Origin will come into play.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to provide some time(100 ms) to submit the form data. Please try this by calling the deleteIframeTimer

```
     function deleteIframeTimer(){
      var t = setTimeout("deleteIframe()", 100);
     }

    function deleteIframe() {
         var iframe = parent.document.getElementById("myframe");
         iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
    }
```